# Plotting a transcendental equation having trigonometric term

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to find a way to plot the solution of an equation got in quantum mechanics,
the equation is of the form
 $ q^2 = 2mE/{\hbar^2} $

I want to plot a graph of cos(qL) vs E ;
[image]

this is the graph that I need.
Please help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 4):

Ti*k*Z has the `plot` operation for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
 \draw (0,-1) rectangle (3*pi,1);
 \draw[dashed] foreach \X in {1,...,5}
  {(\X*\X*pi/12,-1) -- (\X*\X*pi/12,1)};
 \draw[red,thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:36*pi*pi,samples=101,smooth] 
 ({\t/(12*pi)},{cos(sqrt(\t))});
 \path (0,-1) node[left] {$-1$} -- (0,1) node[left]{$1$} 
 node[midway,left]{$0$} (-0.7,0) node[left] (cQL) {$\cos(q\,L)$}
 (4,-1.5)  node(E){$E$};
 \draw[-stealth] (cQL.north) -- ++ (0,0.5);
 \draw[-stealth] (E.east) -- ++ (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is, however, arguably more "natural" to use pgfplots here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xlabel={$E$},ylabel={$\cos(q\,L)$},trig format plots=rad,
 xtick=\empty]
  \addplot[red,thick,domain=0:36*pi*pi,samples=101,smooth]  {cos(sqrt(x))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]